# How to configure SMTP for Azure AD B2C custom emails?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I wan to send customized email for SSO via AD B2C. I see that the [documentation](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol) covers sending custom email via third party providers or via SSPR Technical profile. I'm trying to use the SSPR technical profile.

However, there is no reference as to how the email is sent to the customer. It doesn't explain how the SMTP is configured for AD B2C to be able to send an email from our customized email address. Can someone point of how SMTP is configured for Azure AD B2C.

The documentation for third party emails also don't cover how do we set SMTP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no SMTP.

The SSPR Technical profile uses Azure to send emails. It's all done in the back end.

Similarly, for third parties.

Comment: In that case, how do we use Azure to send email from our personalized email address instead of the MSAL email address?